# MVC website running on localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, localhost

I've built a little time recording website with MVC4, which I'd like to use to record my time.

Previously, coming from a WebForms background, I'd build an app like this and set it up in IIS as an Application off Default Web Site pointing to the folder, so the URL would be `http://localhost/Timesheet`

I tried that with the MVC project, but I get a 500 Internal Server error. I assume this is because it's a project vs. a website. If the project is "running" in Visual Studio, then it works, but I don't want to have to open Visual Studio every time I want to record some task I worked on.

I tried adding it as a separate site under the "Sites" folder in IIS, but then I'm not sure what the Host name should be - it won't allow `localhost/Timesheet` for example.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to wrap the root web.config's system.web section in:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
        ...
    </system.web>
</location>
```